24.04lts 6.8 kernel series ~ suspend/resume issue on 1st use after boot
Scenario: Finally found that the newer 6.8 series of kernels will resume after suspending (used 5.15.0-105-generic a long time [which suspends/resumes fine and leaves my wifi alone] with 24.04lts which does not have this 1st time resume lag issue...) AND not trash my PCI wifi in the process like 20.04lts did, BUT the 1st time I suspend after booting up, it will take almost 5 minutes to resume... after this 1st time it resumes from suspend within seconds like it should.
Question: Why is it taking so long on JUST the 1st suspend/resume, and how can I make it quit?
btw: I'm just glad I finally found a newer kernel that I can use - just this weird 'glitch' which is minor, but curious and would like to find out how to fix it - tried the 'newer' kernels (6.9, 6.10, etc.) but they also have this issue ;-)

off topic... but, the HIBERNATE button is now on my drop down menu - and IT WORKS!!!                        Wow, way to go Ubuntu ;-D

...now, restoring from hibernation goes quicker than resuming the first time from suspend after booting... but, now this 'first time' resume happens less frequently as using hibernate eliminates having to boot and start over with the first resume ;-)

interesting twist - occasionally while browsing a lot with moxilla's firefox, 24.04lts will panic and dumps me out to the login screen. Resuming from logging back in goes pretty quick (like restoring from hibernation does), BUT, when I suspend to RAM after that it acts like it's that 1st suspend/resume after booting and the mouse is dead (no light on the optical mouse) and the computer won't resume for over 5 minutes... after that it suspends/resumes normally (ie quickly in less than a minute like win7 does). More weirdness, but tolerable... and thankfully the PCI wifi is being left alone ;-)
